# How to extract only 5 digit number from a string using REGEXP sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to extract only 5 digit numbers from a string using REGEXP sql in postgresql or redshift DB

For example,

```
f 34 123 54321 123456
```

above string should return

```
54321
```

I am able to get only numbers from string but not only 5 digit number

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('f 34 123 54321 123456', '[^0-9]') five_digit_number
--returns 3412354321123456
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `regexp_matches`.

```
select regexp_matches('f 34 123 54321 123456','\y\d{5}\y','g')
```

Specifying `'g'` flag gives you all the matches in case there is more than one 5 digit occurrence in the string.

`\y` specifies a word boundary.

For Redshift, you can use `regexp_substr`.

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('f 34 123 54321 123456', '(^|[^[:word:]]|[[:space:]])\\d{5}([^[:word:]]|[[:space:]]|$)')
```

Comment: i get ``ERROR: 42883: function regexp_matches("unknown", "unknown") does not exist``

Comment: which version of postgres are you on?

Comment: I use redshift db... REGEXP_REPLACE works but not this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132529/discussion-between-logan-and-vkp).